# Check the class of all <td>'s, find <th> with same class, then update the <td>'s <span> with the text() of the corresponding <th>

Tags: jquery, html

My markup

```
<table class="table--responsive">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="table--responsive__row-1">Header 1</th>
        <th class="table--responsive__row-2">Header 2</th>
        <th class="table--responsive__row-3">Header 3</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="table--responsive__row-1">blah blah
         <span></span>
        </td>
        <td class="table--responsive__row-2">blah blah
         <span></span>
        </td>
        <td class="table--responsive__row-3">blah blah
         <span></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="table--responsive__row-1">blah blah
         <span></span>
        </td>
        <td class="table--responsive__row-2">blah blah
         <span></span>
        </td>
        <td class="table--responsive__row-3">blah blah
         <span></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

What I need to do is loop through each `<td>` within the `<tbody>` and find the corresponding class in the `<th>`. There is no limit as to how many `<th>` there could be. It could be anywhere from 2 to theoretically 100.

Once I find the `<th>` that has the corresponding class to the `<td>` I need to take the text within the corresponding `<th>` and insert it into the `<span>` element of the corresponding `<td>`.

So my markup should end up something like this:

```
<table class="table--responsive">
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="table--responsive__row-1">Header 1</th>
            <th class="table--responsive__row-2">Header 2</th>
            <th class="table--responsive__row-3">Header 3</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="table--responsive__row-1">blah blah
              <span>Header 1</span>
            </td>
            <td class="table--responsive__row-2">blah blah
             <span>Header 2</span>
            </td>
            <td class="table--responsive__row-3">blah blah
             <span>Header 3</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="table--responsive__row-1">blah blah
             <span>Header 1</span>
            </td>
            <td class="table--responsive__row-2">blah blah
             <span>Header 2</span>
            </td>
            <td class="table--responsive__row-3">blah blah
             <span>Header 3</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
```

I need the code to be capable of looping through an unknown amount of the class `table--responsive__row-[i]` pattern.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using `jQuery`.

```
$('table>tbody>tr>td').each(function () {
  let $td = $(this);
  let className = $td.attr('class') ? $td.attr('class').split(' ')[0] : ''; // getting the first class on the `td`, else use a regexp to find the desired class name
  let $th = $(`table>thead>tr>th.${className}`);
  let text = $th.text();
  let $span = $(this).find('span');
  $span.text(text);
});
```

To iterate over all the `tr`

1. select all `tr` using `$('table>tbody>tr>td');`.
2. iterate over them using `each` function.
3. get the class on every `td` using `$(this).att('class')`.
4. find `th` with the class using `$('table>thead>tr>th.${className}')`.
5. get the `text` from the head using `$th.text()`.
6. find the `span` inside the `td` using `$(this).find('span')`.
7. set the `text` on the `span` using `$span.text(text)`.

Comment: Awesome. Please mark it as the answer for future generations =P

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this part jQuery part pseudo code, so please forgive syntax short cuts.

```
var thKeyVal = [];
$('th').foreach(function() {
  thKeyVal[$(this).attr('class')] = $this.text()
}
$('td').foreach(function() {
  $(this).val = thKeyVal[$(this).attr('class')]
}
```

In short, loop through and collect the key:values of the `th` elements. Then loop through the `td` elements and assign value as it matches the keyed array.